# Given specific lat/lon calculate closest point from csv list of lat/lon

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, euclidean-distance

Need help with efficient python code(using pandas) to find which vehicle at what time passed closest to incident_sw =(35.7158, -120.7640).  I'm having trouble formulating a Euclidean distance to sort through below df and print which vehicle and its corresponding time are closest to incident_sw.  All times are HH:MM:SS.SS (assume below times are hour 12).

My time conversion function--

```
def time_convert(str_time):                                                   
values = str_time.split(':')                                                         
mins = 60*(float(values[0]) - 12) + float(values[1]) + 1.0/60 * float(values[2])     
mins = round(mins, 4)                                                                
return mins
```

My csv dataframe--

```
vehicle time    lat[D.DDD]  lon[D.DDD]
veh_1   17:19.5 35.7167809  -120.7645652
veh_1   17:19.5 35.7167808  -120.7645652
veh_1   17:19.7 35.7167811  -120.7645648
veh_1   17:20.1 35.7167812  -120.7645652
veh_2   17:20.4 35.7167813  -120.7645647
veh_2   17:20.7 35.7167813  -120.7645646
veh_3   17:22.6 35.7167807  -120.7645651
veh_3   17:23.4 35.7167808  -120.7645652
veh_4   17:24.1 35.7167803  -120.7645653
veh_4   17:25.0 35.7167806  -120.7645658
veh_5   17:25.9 35.7167798  -120.7645659
veh_5   17:26.6 35.7167799  -120.7645658
```

Comment: so you want to find a better way to calculate (lat, long) distance?

Comment: @linpingta  That is one part of it.  I specifically need to formulate a code to return which vehicle at what time passed closest to incident_sw =(35.7158, -120.7640), which is a separate variable from the csv data.

Comment: so time is an input parameter, and you want veh_id as function output? If you need time accurate equal, then it means filter operation on dataframe, is that right?

Comment: First, I need to calculate distance between all lat/lon in csv df compared to incident_sw lat/lon.  Output is both veh_id and time  for the lat/lon that is closest in distance to incident_sw

Comment: This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38082936/3765319

Comment: @Kartik, I have a hard time understanding how to apply vectorization.  Trying to keep it as simply as possible.

Comment: Why is it hard? It is quite simple. The alternative, IMHO is harder, because you have to code a loop yourself, which just becomes ugly. Think of [`np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) as a loop. It will just loop over whatever you pass, repeatedly calling the function inside.

Comment: The concept seems easier; learning how to implement it is another!  Still learning the basics.  I think it was that question you referenced...it was a confusing example to me.

Answer (score 0):

So, at the outset, I would recommend you use a library like [Geopy](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.0/) to do the heavy lifting of calculating the distances between points. Secondly, I would recommend using [GeoPandas](http://geopandas.org/) to store geographic information. More on that later.

Assuming your distances function is called `distance` (you code it yourself, or get it from Geopy, as you prefer), this will help speed up things for you somewhat. Note that the below implementation is still a loop, even though it uses [`vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) from `numpy` library. Also, the below is pseudo-code, and you will have to modify it to work for you.

```
import numpy as np

def dist_calc(point, list_of_points):
    dist = np.vectorize(lambda x: distance(point, x))
    return dist(list_of_points)

# Now you can call it simply using:
df['points'] = list(zip(df['lat'], df['lon']))
df.groupby('vehicle')['points'].transform(dist_calc, point=incident_sw)
```

---

Reasons for recommending GeoPandas is simple. If you have a huge number of points to search from, say each vehicle leaves a trail of points every minute or second, then the above answer will take a long time to compute. If you are storing your data in a GeoPandas, then you can use the [`buffer`](http://geopandas.org/geometric_manipulations.html#GeoSeries.buffer) and [`intersects`](http://geopandas.org/reference.html#GeoSeries.intersects) tools in GeoPandas to limit the search space around your incidents. In that case, you will build a reasonable size buffer around your incidents, and only search for those vehicle points that fall inside that buffer. That will help speed up your code.

I would recommend you take a day to familiarize yourself with all the capabilities of GeoPandas before proceeding.

---

#### Using great_circle from geopy

```
from geopy import great_circle
import numpy as np

def dist_calc(point, list_of_points):
    dist = np.vectorize(lambda x: great_circle(point, x).meters)
    return dist(list_of_points)

# Now you can call it simply using:
df['points'] = list(zip(df['lat'], df['lon']))
df['distances'] = df.groupby('vehicle')['points'].transform(dist_calc, point=incident_sw)
```

Comment: the incident_sw is only that one given lat/lon and not a column in another df.  I coded a distance formula, but the inputs are lat2, lon2.  Lat1 and lon1 are defined with the incident_sw values.   Are you creating a 'points' column in the above? Not sure where that is coming from.

Comment: You did not include that you had a distance function. You actually said that you had trouble formulating Euclidean distance computation. Hence I recommended using Geopy. But then a simple fix would be to change your distance function to accept `tuples`. Something like: `def myfunc(point2, point1): lat2, lon2, lat1, lon1 = point2, point1` should do the trick...

Comment: The reason it is better to pass the latitude and longitude pairs as `tuples` is because `tuples` are not mutable. The two values will stay together. Especially, if you want to use `np.vectorize` to move things along a bit faster, then it is important to pass them as a list or array of `tuples`, else, your values may be split. In any case, handling code with fewer variables, IMHO, is more maintainable and easier.

Comment: I decided to import geopy for great circle distance.  Not sure how your pseudcode would work with geopy as the distance formula. Also, getting  a type errors with regards to the use of "point"   TypeError: dist_calc() got multiple values for argument 'point'

Comment: See the edit in the answer. It should be pretty clear how to go from here.

Comment: The `incident_sw` should be a `tuple` of (lat, lon) when you send it to `dist_calc`. Like in your question. That should not raise a `multiple value` error.