# How to apply `numpy.vectorize` on a subset of arguments?

Tags: python, numpy

I have searched a lot but couldn't find a solution to this particular problem. I have a function with the following signature:

```
def my_function(self, number: float, lookup: list[str]) -> float:
    # perform some operation
    return some_float_based_on_operation
```

I am trying to vectorize it as follows:

```
my_ndarray = np.vectorize(self.my_function)(my_ndarray, ["a", "b", "c"])
```

where `my_ndarray` is one dimensional array of 18 floats.

But I get the following error when I try to run  the code above:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (18,) (3,)
```

My use case does not need to have both arguments of same length because the second argument is an unrelated list of strings. How can I vectorize such a function?

Comment: Do you need to vectorize your function ? take a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38082936/best-way-to-pass-repeated-parameter-to-a-numpy-vectorized-function

Comment: specify an `exclude`.  But read the performance disclaimer.  `vectorize` is most useful when you need broadcasting.

Comment: Why do you want to use `np.vectorize`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use the `excluded` parameter of [`np.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```py
import numpy as np

def f(x, y):
    assert np.shape(x) == ()
    assert np.shape(y) != ()
    return x*len(y)

f2 = np.vectorize(f, excluded=[1, 'y'])

x = np.arange(3)
y = ['a', 'b', 'c']
f2(x, y)  # array([0, 3, 6])
f2(x, y=y)  # array([0, 3, 6])
```